# Insert statement from a linked server won't insert into the table. What am I missing here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linked-server, openquery

I'm using SQL Server 2016 to attempt to insert records from couple of tables located on a linked server. I can run the query and pull the data that I'm looking for, but when I attempted to insert it into the table it runs successfully, but no data is inserted into the SQL Server table. Here's my code;

```
insert into BTGroup (authorizedgroup, itemno)
select custno, prod 
from OPENQUERY(NxtTest, '
select s.custno, p.prod, p.zauthorized
from pub.zics s 
join pub.csp p on s.prod = p.prod
where p.zauthorized = 1
')
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm new to working with linked servers so I'm a bit lost. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't get any error message and receive a message like `(20 rows affected)` in result window so everything is ok.

Check the selected database that contains `BTGroup` table when you are executing the query or change it to the full address. (e.g. `MyDatabase.dbo.BTGroup`)

Comment: Surprisingly this fixed it. Well at least threw an error to let me know it was a PK constraint causing the data not to flow, then I was able to fix it. Not sure why it didn't just give me that error to begin with. Thank you for the timely assistance though, cheers.

Comment: So you have two or more table named 'BTGroup' in various database. Please mark the answer as accepted if your problem in this question is solved.

Comment: No, it was trying to insert a record that already existed in the database which was causing it to fail as the custno is a PK. I just had to add a 'where not exists' clause after the query against the linked server. When I was not using the full address, the query would say completed. For some reason adding the full address allowed it to raise an error stating a 'Cannot insert.... custno already exists'.